# Matlab conditional assignments

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

```
  if male(m,7)==0||male(m,7)==1
        if female(f,7)==0||female(f,7)==1
            Wfst = 1;
        end
        if female(f,7)==2||female(f,7)==3||female(f,7)==4
            Wfst = 1/2;
        end
        if female(f,7) == -1
            Wfst = 1/2;
        end
    end

    if male(m,7)==2||male(m,7)==3||male(m,7)==4
        if female(f,7)==0||female(f,7)==1
            Wfst = 0;
        end
        if female(f,7)==2||female(f,7)==3||female(f,7)==4
            Wfst = 1;
        end
        if female(f,7) == -1
            Wfst = 1/2;
        end
    end
```

Can anyone suggest a shorter method of dealing with conditional assignments. I have posted the actual code that I am dealing with.

Comment: possible revision of [Conditional Assignment in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498363/conditional-assignment-in-matlab).  Delete one of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`switch/case`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html). Like this:

```
switch male(m, 7)
    case {0, 1}
        switch female(f,7)
            case {0, 1}
                Wfst = 1;
            case {2, 3, 4}
                Wfst = 1/2;
            case -1
                Wfst = 1/2;
        end
    case {2, 3, 4}
        switch female(f,7)
            case {0, 1}
                Wfst = 0;
            case {2, 3, 4}
                Wfst = 1;
            case -1
                Wfst = 1/2;
        end
end
```

It is not shorter than yours, but very easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace

```
a == n1 || a == n2 || a == n3
```

with

```
any(a == [n1, n2, n3])
```

In similar spirit, for the future, if you happened to have `&&` rather than `||`, you can use the matlab function `all` in place of `any`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this really simplifies it much but maybe you can take some elements out of it, so here is a 1 liner that encompasses the same logic:

```
M = male(f, 7)
F = female(f, 7)
Wfst = (M < 2) * ( 1 - any(F == [-1 2:4])*0.5 ) + (M > 1) * ( (F == -1)*0.5 + any(F == 2:4))
```

So the basic idea is that Matlab kind of implicitly converts logical type variables to integers with true being 1 and zero being false so you can just multiply by the condition.

For example:

```
if (a > 10)
   b = 5;
else
   b = 10;
end
```

is the same as

```
b = (a > 10)*5 + ~(a > 10)*10;
```

which simplifies to

```
b = 10 - (a > 10)*5;
```